# Python TKinter Widget "Decimal" validation

Tags: python, validation, tkinter, widget, decimal

I know "more or less" the validation method in Tkinter widgets, but now I want restrict something more complex. I want just the user ables to input number like 0 , 0.5 , 10.5 (between 0-50). No 0.1, no 0.01, no 123.47.

My method is always:

```
def validation_callback(S , P , V):
    ...
self.spinbox = ttk.Spinbox(self.root_frame , from_= 0 , to = 50 , increment = 0.5 , wrap = True , width = 4 , textvariable = self.spin_text_variable , command = lambda: ... , validate = "all" , validatecommand = (self.root_window.register(validation_callback) , "%S" , "%P" , "%V"))
```

Someone can tell me a restriction code to do this?

Thank you very much. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED (by myself):

```
def spin_validations (S , P , V):
    # Key input validations
    if V == "key" and (S[0].isdecimal() or S[0] == ".") and len(P) <= 4:
        return True
    # FocusOut validations
    elif V == "focusout":
        if self.spin.get() != "":
        if (re.fullmatch(r"\d*" , P)) or (re.fullmatch(r"\d+\.[0]" , P)) or (re.fullmatch(r"\d+\.[5]" , P)):
                if float(P) >= 0 and float(P) <= 50:
                    self.spin_variable.set(float(P))
                    return True
                else:
                    self.spin_variable.set(0.0)
                    return False
            else:
                self.spin_variable.set(0.0)
                return False
        else:
            self.spin_variable.set(0.0)
            return False
    else:
        return False

self.spin = ttk.Spinbox(self.root_frame , from_= 0 , to = 50 , increment = 0.5 , wrap = True , width = 4 , textvariable = self.spin_variable , validate = "all" , validatecommand = (self.root.register(spin_validations) , "%S" , "%P" , "%V"))
```